# error while creating session bean

Tags: netbeans, ejb, javabeans

i am trying the 'Hello World! with Remote Stateless Session Bean'example with glassfish3+ and netbeans 7.2 and while creating a session bean i have an error stating-"there is no suitable project available into which Remote interface could be stored. An open Ant-based Java Class Library project is required". what does this mean and how to resolve the problem and how can i proceed.does it require any additional installation.

Comment: what kind of project is it? Ejb Project, web application?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok. So Netbeans tries to enforce best practices on you. in this case it is considered best practice to put your remote interfaces in a separate Java library, because other clients might use it. So Here's the step you should take.

Create a new **Java Class Library** Project
[image]
Right click on your EJB Module, Click properties and add that project to your EJB Modules library.
[image]
Now you should see your Library Class, when you create a new Session Bean with Remote Interface.
[image]